# react-scripts are not executed correctly

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

The standard scripts for create-react-app are no longer running correctly.

As an example, I needed to access the 'start' script directly from node_modules "node node_modules / react-scripts / scripts / start.js".

The same is happening in the test using jest

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  }
```

[image]

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/zehguilherme/personal-curriculum)

Comment: Could you clarify what error you are seeing when you don't access start.js directly? Is it an error from react-scripts or from your application?

Comment: What’s the exact error that you get?

Comment: It is not actually an error in itself, when I run any script with yarn or npm, it is not executed, only the message "Done in 00.0 s" is shown. As I exemplified in the image.

I don't really know if it's a problem with react-scripts or some other dependency on the project itself.

Comment: Did you try npx or Node.js executable directly?

Comment: I tried at that time and it didn't work in the case of the test script ("test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"), only in the start script (as it was previously).